# split 1 column to 2 mysql

Tags: mysql, select

I have this table data

| cars | type |
| --- | --- |
| charger | M |
| challenger | M |
| mustang | M |
| ferrari | S |
| lambo | S |
| buggati | S |

**Expected Output:**

| Musclecar | Supercar |
| --- | --- |
| charger | ferrari |
| challenger | lambo |
| mustang | buggati |

I've tried with the select case but gives me `null`

```
select  
   case when type = 'M' then cars end Musclecar ,
   case when type = 'P' then cars end Supercar 
from carlist
```

**Current Output**

```
| Musclecar | Supercar |
| --------  | -------- |
| charger   | null     |
| challenger| null     |
| mustang   | null     |
| null      | ferrari  |
| null      | lambo    |
| null      | buggati  |
```

Comment: What indication do you have that "charger" matches "ferrari", and not, e.g., "buggati"?

Comment: These columns are unrelated, so it doesn't make sense for these results to be a single row. However, if you still would like to do it for some reason, then JOIN the same table should probably be the solution. In this situation, you must provide join predicates (condition after ON keyword), and there is a logical problem again (as comment above).

Comment: Do you want any type M matched with any type S? What is the logic for the pairing shown? What if there were an uneven number of types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can use a combination of the `CASE` statement and the `ROW_NUMBER` function like this-

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'M' THEN cars END) AS Musclecar,
    MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'S' THEN cars END) AS Supercar
FROM (
    SELECT
        cars,
        type,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY cars) AS row_num
    FROM carlist
) t
GROUP BY row_num;
```

##### This will produce the following output:

```
| Musclecar | Supercar |
| --------  | -------- |
| charger   | ferrari  |
| challenger| lambo    |
| mustang   | buggati  |
```